# `getOrElse` to stop process or return different class type

Tags: scala

Let's say I've this code:

```
val parsedMessage: JsResult[Message] = Json.fromJson(Json.parse(msg))

val message: Message = parsedMessage.getOrElse {
    log.warning("Invalid json: {}", msg)
    RejectedMessageEvent(msg)
}

val newMessageEvent: NewMessageEvent = NewMessageEvent (userId, message.to, message.text)

messagePersistentActor ! message
```

Obviously this fails at compile time because the `getOrElse` doesn't return an object of type `Message`. But let's say, for some reason, the `parsedMessage` fails and I get inside the 'else' part of `getOrElse`. Here I want to either stop the process (in Java it would be a `return`) or return a `RejectedMessageEvent` - which gives a compile error as expected.

As a typical Java developer, I'm keen to use:

```
if(parsedMessage.isError) {
   log.warning("Invalid json: {}", msg)
   messagePersistentActor ! RejectedMessageEvent(msg)
}
else {
   val newMessageEvent: NewMessageEvent = NewMessageEvent (userId, message.to, message.text, UUID.randomUUID().toString, DateTime.now.getMillis)
   messagePersistentActor ! message
}
```

But I feel this is not the best practice for Scala.

How would you solve this case where I either want to stop the process inside the `getOrElse`, or return a different object type than the declared one for that variable?

I know I could omit the Message type declaration at `val message: Message = parsedMessage.getOrElse` and make it simply `val message = parsedMessage.getOrElse`, but then I would not be able to do `message.to` and `message.text` on the `NewMessageEvent` case class constructor because `message` could either be type of `Message` or `RejectedMessageEvent`.

I'm using case classes and I could use the inheritance (`RejectedMessageEvent` and `NewMessageEvent` both extending `Message`), but I'm trying to avoid this solution and go for a more practical one.

Comment: what json library are you using? play?

Comment: Yes, this is a Play Framework project

Comment: `fold` takes a function for invalid and valid, which can side-effect arbitrarily. Similarly for Option.fold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very common in scala to replace `if (someOptValue.isDefined) ... else ...` with this pattern `someOptValue.map(value => ...).getOrElse(...)`:

```
messagePersistentActor ! parsedMessage.map {msg =>
  NewMessageEvent (userId, msg.to, msg.text)
}.getOrElse {
  log.warning("Invalid json: {}", msg)
  RejectedMessageEvent(msg)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`asOpt`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.JsResult@asOpt:Option[A]) instead, and get an `Option` value for your message:

```
val parsedMessage: JsResult[Message] = Json.fromJson(Json.parse(msg))

val message: Option[Message] = parsedMessage.asOpt

message match {
  case Some(m: Message) => messagePersistentActor ! m
  case None => {
    // Log and handle error
  }
}
```